# Ember.js computed property with ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.js ArrayController with a model of People. I'm trying to create a computed property that generates the average of people's weight. It seems like this should be fairly easy, but I'm stuck. Here's my code.

```
App.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  //each model in the array has a "weight" property

  averageWeight: function() {
    //I don't know what to do here
  }.property('@each.weight')
});
```

Handlebars code.

```
{{#each controller}}
   {{name}}
{{/each}}

Average weight: {{weight}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out. For some reason you need to use 'content.@each' to access the model data inside the computed property.

```
averageWeight: function(val) {
    var weights = this.get('content.@each.weight').toArray(); //this is the critical part!

    weights.forEach(function(val)) {
        //calc average here
    }

    return average;
}.property('@each.weight')
```